# Tornado websocket handler , self.close() is closing connection without triggering the on_close() method

Tags: python, web, websocket, tornado

im new at (python, stackoverflow, tornado) , so please,  be patient :). Correct me.

Im working with tornado on a real-time app. When i call self.close() inside the Websocket handler class , the on_close method is not fired up , for this time i did a little wrapper , fixing the problem  and (for example) discarding that connected agent (pure avascript wss api client) correctly.

All network problems are discarded , since my poor wrapper is working nicely and im in a LAN enviroment.

is someone having the same problem ? I cant sleep without an explanation.

THANK YOU , really.

```
## imports and other stuff 

AGENTS = set()     

class BackofficeWSSRailMain(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):   

     def on_open(self):                  
       pass

     def on_message(self,raw_message):
       json_msg=json.loads(raw_message)
       login = function_that_process_login(json_msg)

       if login == True:
          AGENTS.add(self)
          self.write_message("ok")         
       else:
          self.write_message("nologin")
          self.close()         ### this part should fireup 
                               ### the on_close method but nothing 
                               ### happens so AGENT is not discarded.
                               ### here is when i actually call on_close_wrapper(),
                               ### the method below. 

     def on_close_wrapper(self):

       self.close()            ### this is my actual solution , 
                               ### waiting for more research.
       self.on_close()

     def on_close(self):      

       AGENTS.discard(self)

   ## Calling ioloop ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`self.on_close` is executed if and only if the client closes its side of the websocket connection. Try it: If you open a web page that contains a Javascript client which connects to your server, then you close the page, `on_close` will run. `on_close` is not supposed to run if you call `self.close` in your server code.

Your wrapper is a reasonable solution to your problem; that is, it's a reasonable way to ensure that the same code runs either when you call `self.close` or when the client disconnects.

Comment: Wow ! i feel like a noob , thank you very much !! thats exactly what i want to hear. And yes i need to execute the same code in both cases because is an "authenticated websocket secure session", so if the connection fails , the client must do the login process again and re-obtain a new token . Thank you very much !!! long life to stackoverflow  !!!

Comment: what about `on_connection_close()` [link](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/websocket.html#WebSocketHandler)? It is called in both cases, but only if the client closed the connection `on_close()` is called

Comment: So the name on_close() is very bad. If it's called only when the client closes, it should have been close on_client_close()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `on_close()` is only executed if the client closes the connection, so it's a good place to clean up resources.

For any cleanup use the `on_finish()` method documented here https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_finish

Comment: Note, you might need `on_connection_close()` See this thread https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/517

Comment: But the docs say: "Invoked when the WebSocket is closed."