# Close connection with python tornado http client on each call

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, tornado

I am using tornado python to execute non blocking hundreds of calls to an external proxy service.
The external proxy service requires me to use a new connection on every call.

I wrote the following:

```
config = {
        'proxy_host': 'host',
        'proxy_port': port
    }

httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")
for url in urls:
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
    client.fetch(url, callback=callback, headers=headers, **config)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

   def handle_request()
       do_something()
       if io_counter == max_calls:
            ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

However, the service claims that I am using the same connection.

How can I use a different connection on each call?

Comment: Every request is made using a different socket, so it is actually a different connection for every request. Maybe the proxy service requires you to make requests using different IP addresses?

Comment: no, they don't. since this is their service - they need to provide a rotating proxy id. Do I need the force_instance=True in this case?

Comment: I can't say. This question might help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21499722/1925257

Comment: Thanks. will see how to take it on from here

Comment: Try this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121436/tornado-websocket-handler-self-close-is-closing-connection-without-triggerin

Comment: Is there a public proxy or an open source proxy server that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Your code is neither complete nor self-consistent.

Comment: @Isma, unfortunately I dont' have

Comment: @Leon can you please explain?

Comment: @Dejell I meant that your code doesn't meet the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines, thus anyone who doesn't know the answer to your question but is willing to help is being somewhat repelled due to the additional entry barrier

Comment: what is " new connection" mean? new socket?new port?new identity?

Comment: @Dejell, possible to provide name of the service provider?

Comment: is there any way to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prohibit `libcurl` to reuse connections. Quick answer is [`CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE.html).

## Reproduction

In a virtualenv do `pip install proxy.py tornado`. Open two terminal windows and active the virtualenv.

*test.py*

```
import pycurl
from tornado import gen, ioloop, httpclient

urls = ['https://httpbin.org/uuid', 'https://httpbin.org/uuid']
proxy_config = {'proxy_host': '127.0.0.1', 'proxy_port': 8899}

def prepare(curl):
    # curl.setopt(pycurl.FORBID_REUSE, 1)
    pass   

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    for url in urls:
        kwargs = {}
        kwargs.update(proxy_config)
        kwargs['prepare_curl_callback'] = prepare
        response = yield client.fetch(url, **kwargs)
        print(response.body)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
        'tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient')
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

*window #1*

```
$ python test.py
```

*window #2*

```
$ proxy.py --log-level DEBUG 2>&1 | grep -P "(Closing proxy|Proxying connection)"
```

Window #2 two should output something like:

```
2017-10-20 19:03:53,091 - DEBUG - pid:30914 - Proxying connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7fc90f0fe0c0> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55202)
2017-10-20 19:03:53,695 - DEBUG - pid:30914 - Closing proxy for connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7fc90f0fe0c0> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55202)
```

## Solution

Now uncomment `curl.setopt(pycurl.FORBID_REUSE, 1)` and you will see:

```
2017-10-20 19:05:19,492 - DEBUG - pid:30931 - Proxying connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f66de66e0c0> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55214)
2017-10-20 19:05:19,890 - DEBUG - pid:30931 - Closing proxy for connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f66de66e0c0> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55214)
2017-10-20 19:05:19,893 - DEBUG - pid:30932 - Proxying connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f66de66e280> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55218)
2017-10-20 19:05:20,279 - DEBUG - pid:30932 - Closing proxy for connection <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f66de66e280> at address ('127.0.0.1', 55218)
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this answer has been downvoted. It appears to be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example with a dummy server and the socket is never reused. However the connection remains opened.

Try with the headers `Connection: close` and `Proxy-Connection: close` to instruct the server/proxy to close the connection once the request is handled:

```
headers = {
  'Connection': 'close',
  'Proxy-Connection': 'close'
}

for url in urls:
  client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True)
  client.fetch(url, callback=handle_response, headers=headers, **config)
```

Comment: 'Connection': 'close', didn't help. will try with proxy-connection